# XSLT Multiplication returns incorrect result

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the below code for carrying out a simple multiplication using xslt1

```
<observedRate>
<xsl:value-of select="Input * 100"/>
</observedRate>
```

However, when Input = 0.0107 the above returns 1.069999999999999999998 rather than 1.07.

I've come across this problem once or twice in the past and have managed to overcome it by doing something like the below (which works in this case)

```
<observedRate>
<xsl:value-of select="( Input div 10) * 1000"/>
</observedRate>
```

I have a couple of problems with this solution, namely

1. Its a hack and doesn't look very nice
2. I'm not confident that it can handle all of the possible values, given that the value of 'Input' can be to any number of decimal places

So is there a nice solution for multplying using xslt1 which works in all cases where the input variable is not of a defined lengt?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<xsl:value-of select='format-number(Input * 100, "#.00")' />
```

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_formatnumber.asp

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but won't this truncate any values of Input larger than 2dp? For example, if input = 0.01076 this will return 1.08. I need it to return 1.076. I think the big problem is that my input values are not a defined length

Comment: There will always be rounding errors with floating-point arithmetic, and format-number is the simplest way of rounding back to a user-friendly decimal. It's up to you how many digits to present.

Comment: Ok, so I'm getting the impression that what I want isn't possible. Thanks Anyway.

Comment: Yes, it displays as many digits after the decimal point as you specify. To display three digits you wirte `format-number(Input * 100, "#.000")`. If you want more clever formatting you'll have to include scripts in the stylesheet.